# PHP - If Filename Contains...... then move to directory

Tags: php, regex, joomla, joomla3.0

I wonder if you can help. I have loads of files that look like this:

2014-02-10 JB123456G

and this:

2012-02-01 NA657432B

In php i want to filter these files into the relevant directory. So for example "2014-02-10 JB123456G" into the "JB" folder. I thought of doing it as an If statement to find if the filename contains the letters "JB" and then move in to the directory JB. At the moment i have:

```
if(JFile::exists($searchpath .DS. 'JB.png')){
JFile::move($searchpath .DS. 'JB.png', JPATH_BASE .DS. 'upload' .DS. 'JB' .DS. 'JB.png'); }
```

I know i need to change "JB.png" to something but not quite sure what, someone recommended Regex have done some research but not quite sure how to add that in. It does move the file JB.png to the JB folder but obviously it will only move that exact filename and wont move the filename: 2014-02-10 JB123456G.png.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Update:

Here is my full php code:

```
    <?php
echo "Start Moving Files to Folder - Steps 1-7 <br><br>"; 
define( '_JEXEC', 1); 

define('JPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );

if (!defined('DS')){
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );


$parts = explode( DS, JPATH );  
$script_root =  implode( DS, $parts ) ;

// check path
$x = array_search ( 'administrator', $parts  );
if (!$x) exit;

$path = '';

for ($i=0; $i < $x; $i++){
    $path = $path.$parts[$i].DS; 
}
// remove last DS
$path = substr($path, 0, -1);

if (!defined('JPATH_BASE')){
    define('JPATH_BASE', $path );
}    

if (!defined('JPATH_SITE')){
    define('JPATH_SITE', $path );
}    

/* Required Files */
require_once ( JPATH_SITE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_SITE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_SITE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
echo "Step 1 - Required Files Set<br><br>";

//Import filesystem libraries. 

jimport('joomla.filesystem.path');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
jimport('joomla.user.user');

echo "Step 2 - Import Filesystem libraries <br><br>";

//First we set up parameters
$searchpath = JPATH_BASE . DS . "upload";

echo "Step 3 - Set Search Parameters to directory root/upload<br><br>";

//Then we create the subfolder called Images
//if ( !JFolder::create($searchpath . DS ."Images") ) {
   //Throw error message and stop script
//}
//echo "Step 4 - Create Subfolder if necessary <br><br>";

echo "Step 5 - Read all png files and place them into an array <br><br>";
//Now we read all png files and put them in an array.
$png_files = JFolder::files($searchpath,'.png');
$doc_files = JFolder::files($searchpath,'.doc');


echo "Step 6 - Move all files into new folder <br><br>";
//Now we need some stuff from the JFile:: class to move all files into the new folder
if(JFile::exists($searchpath .DS. 'j.png')){
    JFile::move($searchpath .DS. 'j.png', JPATH_BASE .DS. 'upload' .DS. 'Nathan' .DS. 'j.png'); }



echo "Step 7 - Move the whole subdirectory to the root of the component<br><br>";
//Lastly, we are moving the complete subdir to the root of the component.
if (JFolder::move($searchpath . DS. ".png",JPATH_BASE) ) {
   //Redirect with perhaps a happy message
} else {
   //Throw an error


            }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can splite the name of the file with a white space, which will give you an array of two elements `2014-02-10` and `JB123456G` then use substring to cut the first two elements of the string, and based on that you can move your file.

Comment: Ah ok how do i do that? I'm  New to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

explode will help you splite your string : `$array = explode(' ', $filename);` then you can substring the two first elements of the `$array[1]` which is JB123456G for example at this point, `$firstTwoLetters = string substr ($array[1], 0, 2);`

use the PHP online manual, it will help you know everything about all PHP functions.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php

Comment: I get undefined variable filename.... is that something i need to import at the top?

Comment: I have included the full code above.
I'm Looking to add what you have put above into that code but it turns out blank. I basically have an upload folder in the root of where my Joomla installation files are. I have in that folder on of the example files i put above. So i need to place all files into an array, search that array/filename for say JB i then want to split it apart using the explode to get the JB123456G i then need a way of then moving that specific folder into the JB folder? I also was wondering will i need to add code for everyone other person like NS123456 to NS folder?

Comment: Also since i have loads of files like them will i have to specify every file? Or can i get it to search through an array for the specific letter or initials of a person